# Browser won't load file with .objjs extension due to MIME type

Tags: javascript, html, webstorm, mime-types, src

I've run this code in Chrome on my Windows 8 partition and in Firefox on my Ubuntu 14.04 partition. Both give me error messages related to MIME type.

```
   <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/cube.objjs"></script>
    </head>
```

Note: The type doesn't seem to matter, I've tried `type=text/javascript`, `type=application/javascript`, `type=javascript`, and not type at all and I still get the same error messages.

The error message for Chrome on Windows is

> Refused to execute script from
>   `http://localhost:63342/***/GraphicsTownJS2015-master/resources/cube.objjs`
>   because its MIME type ('application/octet-stream') is not executable,
>   and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

And the error message for Firefox on Ubuntu is

> The resource from
>   `http://localhost:63342/***/GraphicsTownJS2015-master/resources/cube.objjs`
>   was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

Here's `cube.objjs`

```
var LoadedOBJFiles = LoadedOBJFiles || {} ;
LoadedOBJFiles["cube_ex.obj"]= {}
LoadedOBJFiles["cube_ex.obj"].vertices = [[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,1,0],[1,1,1]]
LoadedOBJFiles["cube_ex.obj"].normals = [[0,0,1],[0,0,-1],[0,1,0],[0,-1,0],[1,0,0],[-1,0,0]]
LoadedOBJFiles["cube_ex.obj"].texCoords = []
LoadedOBJFiles["cube_ex.obj"].groups = {}
LoadedOBJFiles["cube_ex.obj"].groups['cube' ] = {}
LoadedOBJFiles["cube_ex.obj"].groups['cube' ].vertices = LoadedOBJFiles["cube_ex.obj"].vertices
LoadedOBJFiles["cube_ex.obj"].groups['cube' ].normals = LoadedOBJFiles["cube_ex.obj"].normals
LoadedOBJFiles["cube_ex.obj"].groups['cube' ].texCoords = LoadedOBJFiles["cube_ex.obj"].texCoords
LoadedOBJFiles["cube_ex.obj"].groups['cube' ].faces = [[[0,null,1],[6,null,1],[4,null,1]],[[0,null,1],[2,null,1],[6,null,1]],[[0,null,5],[3,null,5],[2,null,5]],[[0,null,5],[1,null,5],[3,null,5]],[[2,null,2],[7,null,2],[6,null,2]],[[2,null,2],[3,null,2],[7,null,2]],[[4,null,4],[6,null,4],[7,null,4]],[[4,null,4],[7,null,4],[5,null,4]],[[0,null,3],[4,null,3],[5,null,3]],[[0,null,3],[5,null,3],[1,null,3]],[[1,null,0],[5,null,0],[7,null,0]],[[1,null,0],[7,null,0],[3,null,0]]]
LoadedOBJFiles["cube_ex.obj"].groups['cube' ].material ='null'
```

I'm running this code from the WebStorm IDE in both cases. Any ideas as to what I can do to fix this?

Here's the github page for the webapp that generates objjs files
https://github.com/Squeakrats/OBJLoader

Comment: I feel like that should be: `resources/cube.obj.js` since the file is just a JavaScript file (albeit there are no semi-colons at the ends of each statement) . Are you sure you have the file name correct in the first place?

Comment: Seems like you cannot change the built-in mime-types https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206339659-Built-in-Web-Server-settings Which means you should either change the extension to `.js`, or use a better webserver.

Comment: File name is correct, I'm confident in that much. @zerkms how would I go about finding a better webserver to use exactly? Also, thanks for finding my problem for me.

Comment: Uhm, every "proper" webserver allows you to set a mime-type based on the extension. So you would set `.objjs` to be of a `text/javascript` type.

Comment: What is purpose of `.objjs` extension?

Comment: @NebulousRyan Based on URLs .. you most likely using WebStorm's simple built-in web server .. which does not allow you to modify MIME response headers (sent by web server). Install yourself Apache (e.g. XAMPP/WAMP/Wnmp/etc bundle.. or just standalone Apache/nginx) and then configure WebStorm to use them (Deployment entry part .... where you can specify URLs).

Comment: @guest271314  I edited a link into the post of a github page which explains the purpose of the objjs extension

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize `fetch()` to retrieve `.objjs` file, create a `<script>` element with `.textContent` set to promise value of `.text()`

```
window.onload = () => {
  fetch("resources/cube.objjs")
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(obj => {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.textContent = obj;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
    console.log(LoadedOBJFiles);
  })
}
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/WFDIhnsIjYJ8T8ExAdvj?p=preview